# Option doesn't happen when opening vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, set

I added this line to my .vimrc: `set formatoptions-=ro`. When I open any file it works as intended, except if it is .vimrc. In that case it doesn't work. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The FileType plugin for vim files sets the format options. It contains the following line:

```
setlocal fo-=t fo+=croql
```

If you want to overwrite this, create the file `.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim` and add your personal `formatoptions` to it.

When Vim loads the `.vimrc` it will first load the global `vim.vim` FileType plugin and then load `.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim`. So you can overwrite any settings from there.

See `:help after-directory`.